# copy node attributes to parent node

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Im working with PHP5, and I need to transform XML in the following form:

```
<section>
      <heading>
            <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="35">A Heading</line>
      </heading>
      <subsection type="type1">
            <heading label="3">
                  <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="36">A Subheading</line>
            </heading>
            <content/>
      </subsection>
</section>
```

Into something like this:

```
<section name="A Heading">
      <heading>
            <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="35">A Heading</line>
      </heading>
      <subsection type="type1" label="3" name="A Subheading">
            <heading label="3">
                  <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="36">A Subheading</line>
            </heading>
            <content/>
      </subsection>
</section>
```

Note that the `label` attribute has been been copied from the heading attribute to the parent element.

Also the text of the `heading/line` element has been added as an attribute of the `heading` parent node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="subsection">
        <subsection label="{heading/@label}" name="{heading/line}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </subsection>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <section name="{heading/line}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </section>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<section name="A Heading">
    <heading>
        <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="35">A Heading</line>
    </heading>
    <subsection label="3" name="A Subheading" type="type1">
        <heading label="3">
            <line absolutePage="4" page="2" num="36">A Subheading</line>
        </heading>
        <content></content>
    </subsection>
</section>
```

**Note**: Whenever is posible to use literal result elements and attributes value template, use it. That make code compact and fast. If you want more general answer, clarify that please.

**Edit**: Missed `section/@name`. Of course, if empty string `section/@label` doesn't bother you you could use `section|subsection` pattern matching.

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks works great, just add the OR match for 'section', that is missing. :)

Comment: @Benjamin Ortuzar: You are wellcome. I've updated the answer, too.

Comment: +1 for using and overriding the Identity transform and for using AVTs